# Reputation shown on User's Search page is NOT same as on User Profile - NOWHERE close even

Tags: feature-request

I have seen this bug lingering here for long enough time. When we click user's tab https://stackoverflow.com/users, and click on any particular user. What we can see that all the **user's Reputation shown there is NOT same as that on the user profile page**.

I think, this bug should be worked upon as soon as it can be.
What do you say?

Comment: What you're seeing on that link of users is the reputation they gained for the week (by default). You can change it to Week, Month, Quarter, Year, or All.

Comment: I don't think so.It's not of week even. And if it's of week, then there shuold be a word saying (week) or (month) or (total) or (year).

Comment: Do you see where it says Week, Month, Quarter, Year, All over on the top right? Week is underlined.

Comment: ok.. tabs for all...It's right top corner. thanks got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be a bit easy to miss, but you're currently seeing the totals for the week, not all time. We do this intentionally because we think it's more valuable to see who's been active recently rather than the same 20 people who have the highest reputation all-time.

You can see the tab selections here:

[image: Tab with "week" underlined to indicate the totals for the week]

What it took me time to realize is that not only are those users the top reputation earners for the week, that amount is the reputation they've earned so far this week.

If you'd like to see the total reputation of the top all-time users or the top users for longer periods of time, select them using the tab switcher.

Do note that these numbers are for fixed calendar dates, not a rolling month ("last 30 days) or quarter or year. This is why, currently, you'll see the same exact content on the month, quarter and year tabs. Being January, the current reputation earned for the month also represents the reputation earned by these users for 2019.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everyone gets confused the first time they see this. Is there a good reason why it doesn't just default to "all"?

Comment: Explained in the first paragraph.